# apt and dpkg fail because of very broken python

Tags: apt, python, dpkg

apt and dpkg fail with the same underlying python (3.8.2) message.
I am running 20.04

For example running this:
sudo apt-get -f install

Gives this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 47 not to upgrade.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/47.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-jinja2:
 python3-jinja2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
```

So far no net advice have worked or usually executed because of the underlying python fail.
It looks i like i need to fix my installation but my tools are dependent on python.

Advice and suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: sadly no. because python is broken apt install fails, as does dpkg -i

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you re-install the operating system after backing up your Home folder.

Comment: It won't work if python is broken.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Commands like `cp` should work without python. It works in Arch Linux, where python is not preinstalled.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi this answer has been completely rewritten since I commented. Check the edit history. Originally it said to use synaptic to install python.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Makes sense. Anyway, this answer could have been a comment instead.